# Powershell httplistener handle more than one request at the same time

Tags: powershell, httprequest, httpresponse, httplistener

I´m using a normal powershell httplistener script.
The script listenes on port 80 and gives an response.

Now I tried to handle more than one request as the same time. The problem is that the second respons has to wait until the first response was finished by the script.

I tried to start an own job for every http-request - but I can´t send a response to the listener from the PS-Job.

Does anyone know, how to handle parallel httprequests in PS?

Here is the Script I´m using:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/'
$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener
$listener.Prefixes.Add($url)
$listener.Start()

Write-Host "Listening at $url..."

while ($listener.IsListening)
{
$context = $listener.GetContext()
$requestUrl = $context.Request.Url
$response = $context.Response

Write-Host ''
Write-Host "> $requestUrl"

$localPath = $requestUrl.LocalPath
$route = $routes.Get_Item($requestUrl.LocalPath)

if ($route -eq $null)
{
$response.StatusCode = 404
}
else
{
$content = & $route
$buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content)
$response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
$response.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)

}
$response.Close()

$responseStatus = $response.StatusCode
Write-Host "< $responseStatus"
}
```

What is the right way to handle more than one request at the same time?
Thanks @all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple runspaces (even the runspace pool) within the same PowerShell process.  See this [blog post](http://nivot.org/post/2009/01/22/CTP3TheRunspaceFactoryAndPowerShellAccelerators) for details on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both examples - but every request is waiting for the other one in the first beginning pipeline...

I let count the script to 1,000,000 after sending the response (that works). While counting in Pipe 1 I start an request by an another browser and it´s waiting while the first pipe finished.

Could you help me?

Comment: @Florian Where is $routes coming from?

Comment: Hi Keith,

$routes is in the scriptblock like this:

$routes = @{
"/ola" = { return '<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>' }
}

Comment: Is it possible that you write / change the code that it will works?
Imortant is, that the requests can be handled parallel, because the 2nd, 3rd, ... could not wait until...

Comment: I wrestled around with this for a good while yesterday and ran into one fundamental issue with Register-ObjectEvent, PowerShell processes the registered callbacks sequentially.  So even though I was able to get multiple BeginGetContext() to spin up, the callback that happens to service the request effectively gets serialized. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check the $request.url.LocalPath or another one of the url properties depending on how much of context you are looking for.
Provide a different response depending on the request.

```
$htmlout = "<html><link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""MyStleSheet.css""><body class=""body"" />Hello World</body></html>"
$css = ".body {background-color: white;font-size: 20px;font-family: calibri;}"
while($Listener.IsListening -and $noBreak){
 $Context = $listener.GetContext()
 $request = $context.request
 if($request.url.LocalPath -match '.css')
 {
   $buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::utf8.getbytes($css)
 }
 if($request.url.LocalPath -match '.html')
 {
   $buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::utf8.getbytes($htmlout)
 }
 $response = $context.response
 $response.contentlength64 = $buffer.length
 $response.OutputStream.Write($buffer,0,$buffer.length)
}
```